# Derived Safe Class from NSObject class for JSON parsing in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, nsobject

In JSON parsing, model class must need to key coding compliant with JSON response. So following answer must be helpful to preventing it from crashing the iOS App at runtime and print the missing key compliant in console.

Answer (score 0):

```
//
// MARK:- SafeJsonObject
//
@objcMembers
class SafeJsonObject: NSObject {

    override func setValue(_ value: Any?, forKey key: String) {

        let uppercasedFirstCharacter = String(key.first!).uppercased()
        let range = NSMakeRange(0, 1)
        let selectorString = NSString(string: key).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: uppercasedFirstCharacter)

        let selector = NSSelectorFromString("set\(selectorString):")
        let responds = self.responds(to: selector)

        if !responds {
            print("\n\n\n*******--->\(selector) key is missing in API response...<---*******\n\n\n")
            return
        }
        super.setValue(value, forKey: key)
    }
}
```

PC & reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Xv1mJvwXok&list=PL0dzCUj1L5JGKdVUtA5xds1zcyzsz7HLj